# How can I store a generic function into a variable?

Tags: swift

I'm relatively new to Swift and having some trouble understanding how functions work as "first class citizens".

For example, I know to get a simple function, store it into a variable, and later call it:

```
let a = [1,2,3,4]
let fn = a.lastIndex
print(type(of: d)) // stdout: (Int) -> Optional<Int>
print(d(1)) // stdout: Optional(0)
```

More complex functions that have generics are a bit less straight forward. I can't seem to understand the syntax for it. For this case how do I tell the the declaration what the generic type is?

```
let a = [1,2,3,4]
let fn = a.map // Error: Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred

// Tried let fn = a.map<T> but that doesn't work either.
```

A stranger error message that I don't fully understand is the following case

```
import Collections

let a = Deque<Int>([1,2,3,4])
let fn = a.prepend // error: cannot reference 'mutating' method as function value
```

Does the above imply that you can't store functions that are marked as `mutating` in variables?

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot store functions with generic arguments in a variable. It is a limitation of the language.

Comment: By the way, your last code example is a totally different problem from the first two. I tried to searching StackOverflow, but to my surprise, there's no existing Q/A that explains that error. You should consider opening a question for it, I think that'll be valuable.

Comment: ... but in short, the correctness guarantees of structs only exist if their mutability is tightly controlled. If mutating methods were allowed to be captured as function values, those could be passed around to other parts of the program, and executed at arbitrary points in the future. This would lead to the exact kind of shared mutable state that's implicit to `class`es, which is precisely what structs are designed to avoid.

Comment: By the way (2), `Deque` conforms to `ExpressibleByArrayLiteral`, so you can just write: `let a: Deque = [1,2,3,4]`

Comment: @Alexander Thanks for the responses. That all makes sense. I'll find some time to open a question. I posted here cause I couldn't find anything on Google search :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't assign unevaluated generic functions to a local variable, but depending on the circumstance, what you can do is wrap the call in a closure, and store that:

```swift
let a = [1,2,3,4]
let fn = { (transform: (Int) -> Int) in a.map(transform) } // Has type ((Int) -> Int)) -> [Int]
print(fn { $0 * 10 })
```